# Excel VBA, creating a PPT presentation. Different errors each time the code is executed

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint, libraries

thank you for taking the time to read this.

What I am doing:
I trying to create a PPT file from Excel. I copy and paste de contents (ranges and charts) from excel to PPT, beyond that, I also create and edit text boxes.

Errors:
Sometimes the code runs flawlessly (x<10%), but most of the times I get an error. The errors that I get vary from time to time and highlight different pieces of code that work in other sections of the code (that never present an error)

Error A: Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be)':
Automation error, the remote procedure call failed

Error B: Run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

```
'Create PPT
 Option Explicit

 Sub create_ppt()
 Dim pp_app As PowerPoint.Application
 Dim pp_pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
 Dim pp_slide As PowerPoint.Slide
 Dim pp_textB As PowerPoint.Shape

 Set pp_app = New PowerPoint.Application

 pp_app.Visible = msoTrue
 pp_app.Activate

 Set pp_pres = pp_app.Presentations.Add

 'First Slide
Set pp_slide = pp_pres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)

pp_slide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "xxx"
pp_slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "xxx"

 'Second Slide
Set pp_slide = pp_pres.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutBlank)
pp_slide.Select

Excel.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Dashboard_Frame").Copy
pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject
pp_slide.Shapes(1).Width = 775
pp_slide.Shapes(1).Height = 400
pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue
pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue


'Title
    Set pp_textB = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 80, 30, 500, 50)

    With pp_textB.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "xxx"
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 20
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .MarginLeft = 0
    End With

'Source
    Set pp_textB = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 80, 480, 400, 20)

    With pp_textB.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "xxx"
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 11
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .MarginLeft = 0
    End With

 'Third Slide
Set pp_slide = pp_pres.Slides.Add(3, ppLayoutBlank)
pp_slide.Select

Excel.Sheets("Portfolio Comparison").ChartObjects("Comp_GR_YP").Activate
Excel.ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
pp_slide.Shapes.Paste.Select
pp_slide.Shapes(1).Width = 800
pp_slide.Shapes(1).Height = 400
pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue

'Title
    Set pp_textB = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 80, 30, 500, 50)

    With pp_textB.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "xxx"
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 20
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .MarginLeft = 0
    End With

'Source
    Set pp_textB = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 80, 480, 400, 20)

    With pp_textB.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "xxx"
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 11
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .MarginLeft = 0
    End With
 'Fourth Slide
Set pp_slide = pp_pres.Slides.Add(4, ppLayoutBlank)
pp_slide.Select

Excel.Sheets("Portfolio Comparison").ChartObjects("Comp_GR_PY").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
pp_slide.Shapes.Paste.Select
pp_slide.Shapes(1).Width = 800
pp_slide.Shapes(1).Height = 400
pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue

'Title
    Set pp_textB = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 80, 30, 500, 50)

    With pp_textB.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "xxx"
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 20
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .MarginLeft = 0
    End With

'Source
    Set pp_textB = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 80, 480, 400, 20)

    With pp_textB.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "xxx"
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 11
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .MarginLeft = 0
    End With


 'Fifth Slide

Set pp_slide = pp_pres.Slides.Add(5, ppLayoutBlank)
pp_slide.Select

'Growth Chart
    Excel.Sheets("Portfolio").ChartObjects("Growth_port_").Activate
    Excel.ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    pp_slide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    pp_slide.Shapes(1).Width = 600
    pp_slide.Shapes(1).Height = 400
    pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignLefts, msoTrue
    pp_app.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue

    'Title
        Set pp_textB = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
            msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 80, 30, 500, 50)

        With pp_textB.TextFrame
            .TextRange.Text = "xxx"
            .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
            .TextRange.Font.Size = 20
            .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            .MarginLeft = 0
        End With

    'Source
        Set pp_textB = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
            msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 80, 480, 400, 20)

        With pp_textB.TextFrame
            .TextRange.Text = "xxx"
            .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
            .TextRange.Font.Size = 11
            .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            .MarginLeft = 0
        End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely a timing error due to the slow speed of I/O compared to your VBA. Search on _Sleep_, _Wait_ and _DoEvents_ to slow down your code during critical operations.

Comment: Try also to avoid the `.Select` and `.Activate`statements. This is causing havoc as well. You won't need them typically.